# What design pattern is appropriate for this situation?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have 2D hydraulic data, which are multigigabyte text files containing depth and velocity information for each point in a grid, broken up into time steps. Each timestep contains a depth/velocity value for every point in the grid. So you could follow one point through each timestep and see how its depth/velocity changes. I want to read in this data one timestep at a time, calculating various things - the maximum depth a grid cell achieves, max velocity, the number of the first timestep where water is more than 2 feet deep, etc. The results of each of these calculations will be a grid - max depth at each point, etc.

So far, this sounds like the Decorator pattern. However, I'm not sure how to get the results out of the various calculations - each calculation produces a different grid. I would have to keep references to each decorator after I create it in order to extract the results from it, or else add a `getResults()` method that returns a map of different results, etc, neither of which sound ideal.

Another option is the Strategy pattern. Each calculation is a different algorithm that operates on a time step (current depth/velocity) and the results of previous rounds (max depth so far, max velocity so far, etc). However, these previous results are different for each computation - which means either the algorithm classes become stateful, or it becomes the caller's job to keep track of previous results and feed them in. I also dislike the Strategy pattern because the behavior of looping over the timesteps becomes the caller's responsibility - I'd like to just give the "calculator" an iterator over the timesteps (fetching them from the disk as needed) and have it produce the results it needs.

Additional constraints:

- Input is large and being read from disk, so iterating exactly once, by time step, is the only practical method
- Grids are large, so calculations should be done in place as much as possible

Comment: is this really a "design pattern" problem?

Comment: Patterns are helpful when you need to organize your program, however this strikes me more of a "lack of an appropriate algorithm" issue, and I can't help you much with that.  However my advice would be to make a first pass to consume the input and retain only the information you require.  Then use model-view pattern to visualize the data in various ways using what you gathered your first pass.  It's here that you can perform more strenuous calculations from your data.

Comment: Firstly, trying to pigeon hole a design problem into a design pattern is pretty much the exact opposite of the entire philosophy of design patterns.  But I still don't understand the problem well enough - should calculations happen as data comes in or as it is requested?  I don't understand what you mean by iteration/hard disk reading constraint - does this mean data reading should be minimal and with minimal caching?  Can some or all of the algorithms be memoized?  What are the performance constraints?  Etc.

Comment: Basically, I have multigigabyte text files containing depth and velocity information for each grid cell, broken up into timesteps. Each timestep contains a depth/velocity value for every point in the grid. So you could follow one point through each timestep and see how its depth/velocity changes. I want to read in this data one timestep at a time, calculating various things - the maximum depth a grid cell achieves, max velocity, the number of the first timestep where water is more than 2 feet deep, etc. The results of each of these calculations will be a grid - max depth at each point, etc.

Comment: are the calculations unknown at compile time, or are you working with a well known, fixed set of calculations?

Comment: The total set of calculations are known and are unlikely to change. However, which subset of calculations to run are not known until runtime. The user may only be interested in maximum velocity, and thus only needs to run the maxv calculations.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem right, you have a grid_points which have many timesteps & each timestep has depth & velocity. Now have GBs of data.

I would suggest to do one pass on the data & store the parsed data in a RDBMS. then run queries or stored procedures on this data. This way at least the application will not run out of memory

Answer (score 0):

First, maybe I've not well understood the issue and miss the point in my answer, in which case I apologize for taking your time.

At first sight I would think of an approach that's more akin to the "strategy pattern", in combination with a data-oriented base, something like the following pseudo-code:

```
foreach timeStamp

  readGridData

  foreach activeCalculator in activeCalculators

    useCalculatorPointerListToAccessSpecificStoredDataNeededForNewCalculation

    performCalculationOnFreshGridData

    updateUpdatableData

    presentUpdatedResultsToUser

    storeGridResultsInDataPool(OfResultBaseClassType)

    discardNoLongerNeededStoredGridResults

  next calculator
next timeStep
```

Again, sorry if this is off the point.